# Multi-master database replication with Django webapp and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, multi-master-replication

I am working on scaling out a webapp and providing some database redundancy for protection against failures and to keep the servers up when updates are needed. The app is still in development, so I have chosen a simple multi-master redundancy with two separate database servers to try and achieve this. Each server will have the Django code and host its own database, and the databases should be as closely mirrored as possible (updated within a few seconds).

I am trying to figure out how to set up the multi-master (master-master) replication between databases with Django and MySQL. There is a lot of documentation about setting it up with MySQL only (using various configurations), but I cannot find any for making this work from the Django side of things.

From what I understand, I need to approach this by adding two database entries in the Django settings (one for each master) and then write a database router that will specify which database to read from and which to write from. In this scenario, both databases should accept both reads and writes, and writes/updates should be mirrored over to the other database. The logic in the router could simply use a round-robin technique to decide which database to use. From there on, further configuration to set up the actual replication should be done through MySQL configuration.

Does this approach sound correct, and does anyone have any experience with getting this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of the router is great! I would add that you need automatically detect whether a databases is [slow] down. You can detect that by the response time and by connection/read/write errors. And if this happens then you exclude this database from your round-robin list for a while, trying to connect back to it every now and then to detect if the databases is alive.

In other words the round-robin list grows and shrinks dynamically depending on the health status of your database machines.

The another important notice is that luckily you don't need to maintain this round-robin list common to all the web servers. Each web server can store its own copy of the round-robin list and its own state of inclusion and exclusion of databases into this list. This is just because a database server can be seen from one web server and can be not seen from another one due to local network problems.